# Move the menus to their window menu bars

Tags: 16.04, xfce

I migrated from ubuntu 16.04 to the xfce4-panel 4.12.0 environment as I  installed ubuntu-studio.

The menus of an application window ("file", "edit", "option", "tools"...) appear in one of the screen bars when i add the 'indicator' plugin.

I'd rather have those menus in their own windows (where they belong imho). Is there a way to do that with this desktop? in gnome there is the appearance / behavior checkbox that will put the menus in the application window bar, that would be perfect if this existed but i haven't found a way to do the same in xfce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do that:

- Right click on the panel where the 'indicator plugin' is displayed
- Panel
- Panel Preferences
- Choose the items tab
- Select 'indicator plugin'
- click the settings wheel on the right side or double click the 'indicator plugin' line
- Check the hidden checkbox in front of 'Application Menus (Global Menu)'
- Close

You have to log out and log back to make it work.